# How to migrate wordpress DB to crafter CMS?

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, database-migration, crafter-cms

I have wordpress data dumb, and I want to migrate to crafter CMS.
Don't know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

CrafterCMS is Git-based and stores content as XML files. You will have to export the WordPress posts, convert them to XML (and comply with the model you would build in CrafterCMS), and then add them to Git and it'll run. A blueprint like Editorial or Wordify would be a good target for such a migration since they're blog-gish.

Comment: So there's no tool, so plugin for this.

Comment: Correct. There is no out-of-the-box migration tool/plugin. Might be a fun open source contribution, however.

Comment: That's what I am thinking about